# How can I get element using xpath?

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml, domdocument

I'm trying to get some data from a HTML

```
$xdata = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
$datas = $xdata->xpath("//*[@class='proglist']");
$aData = array();
foreach($datas as $data)
{   

    $rightdatas = $data->xpath("*[@class='progright']");
    $rt = $rightdatas[0];
    print_r($rt);
    $content  = $rt->xpath("*[@class='progrighthead']");
    print_r($content  );
}
```

If I'm printing out the content of the `$rt` than the `progrighthead` class is there, but the `$content` variable is empty. Why?

Why do I receiving the same result for the following syntax?

```
$xdata = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
$datas = $xdata->xpath("//*[@class='proglist']");
$aData = array();
foreach($datas as $data)
{   

    $rightdatas = $data->xpath("*[@class='progright']");
    $rt = $rightdatas[0];
    print_r($rt);
    $content  = $rt->xpath("*[@class='progrighthead']");
}
```

and

```
$datas    = $xdata->xpath("//*[@class='progrighthead']");
```

Comment: Could you include the loaded document please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

progrighthead is not a child of progright, but a descendant. Use

```
$rt->xpath(".//*[@class='progrighthead']");
```

Putting `//` at the beginning means searching from the root, not from the current element.